# How to replace square root symbol in a string?

Tags: android, string, unicode, character-encoding, square-root

In my android app I'm using

```
String sqrt = "\u221a";
editText.setText(sqrt);
```

to display the square root symbol. And whatever mathematical expression is entered in that editText is going to be evaluated. The math library I'm using evaluates valid expressions when they are passed as strings. Square root must be like this:

```
sqrt(number)
```

So I need to replace the the square root symbol in the string I get from the edit text:

```
String input = editText.getText().toString();
input.replace(sqrt,"sqrt("); //doesn't work!
```

Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: May be you can convert string to ascii characters and remove ascii code for sqrt from it.

Answer (score 3):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

String sqrt = "\u221a";
editText1.setText(sqrt);

String input = editText1.getText().toString();
String new1 = input.replace(sqrt, "sqrt(");
editText1.setText(new1);
```